# JQuery variable in HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I want to display variable `fullScript` in the HTML below.
I tried this, but it did not work.
What am I doing wrong?

**JQUERY**

```
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            var fullDate = new Date();console.log(fullDate);
            var twoDigitMonth = fullDate.getMonth()+"";if(twoDigitMonth.length==1)  twoDigitMonth="0" +twoDigitMonth;
            var twoDigitDate = fullDate.getDate()+"";if(twoDigitDate.length==1) twoDigitDate="0" +twoDigitDate;
            var currentDate = fullDate.getFullYear() +"-"+ twoDigitMonth + "-" +  twoDigitDate;
            var currentTime = fullDate.getHours() +":"+ fullDate.getMinutes()
            console.log(currentDate);
            console.log(currentTime);


            var fullScript = "/opt/fings/interface/postEnginInstruction.py --call --viewdevicedata 130150000008 "+currentDate+" "+currentTime+" False";
            console.log(fullScript);
            $('#fullScript').html(fullScript);
        });
```

**HTML**

```
                <span>
                    <label for="fullScript" class="frm_label">Script to run</label>
                    <div class="frmFull"><input type="text" class="editBox readonly" id="fullScript" name="fullScript"/></div>
                </span>
```

PS - `console.log(fullScript);` is displaying 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the value of an input, use `val`, not `html` :

```
$('#fullScript').val(fullScript);
```

Comment: agghhh. yeah I should have known. Thanks anyway for stating the obvious. sometimes it does help

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.val()` instead of `.html()` for setting variable to `input`

Change this

```
$('#fullScript').html(fullScript);
```

to

```
$('#fullScript').val(fullScript);
```